# Find the matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$, $B$ $\in R^{n\times n}$, $A$, $B$, $AB-I$ are invertible and $I$ is the identity matrix, then

a) Find the inverse matrix of $A-B^{-1}$.

b) Find the inverse matrix of $(A-B^{-1})^{-1}-A^{-1}$.

No clue...

Comment: What is $P^{n \times n}$?

Comment: For part (a), notice that $A-B^{-1} = (AB-I)B^{-1}$, so $(A-B^{-1})^{-1}=B(AB-I)^{-1}$. Part (b) should have a similar approach - find a way to represent that matrix as a product of invertible matrices that you do know.